# Use Lagrange multipliers to find the minimum distance from the curve or surface to the indicated point

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, lagrange-multiplier

The given curve is the parabola $y=x^2$ with point $(0,9)$.

We want to minimize $D^2=f(x,y)=x^2 + (y-9)^2$ with the constraint equation $g(x,y) =y-x^2=0$.

After finding the gradients of both $f$ and $g$ we get:
$$2x = -2 \lambda x$$
$$2y-18=\lambda$$
Plugging in $\lambda$ from our $y$ equation into the $x$ equation yields that either
$$x=0$$
$$y=\frac{19}{2}$$
When $x=0$ then $y=0$ and when $y=\frac{19}{2}$ then $x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{19}{2}}\space$,we cant to minimize the equation so we use the negative.
Using these values of $x$ and $y$ in $D^2$ gives
$$D^2=\sqrt{\frac{39}{4}}$$
$$D=\frac{\sqrt{39}}{2}$$
But this is where I run into a problem because $\frac{\sqrt{39}}{2}=9.75$ which is greater than my original point. So how do I find the lowest point then?

Comment: solving the equations gives you, $y=0, x=0, \lambda=-18$. Also, note that because this is not a convex problem, then KKT conditions are not sufficient. So, you should check all the KKT points to find the minimum.

Comment: I haven't learned what KKT points are.

Comment: I meant all the solutions of that satisfy your equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x,y,\lambda) = x^2 + (y-9)^2 - \lambda (x^2 - y)\\
\frac {\partial f}{\partial x} = 2x (1-\lambda) = 0\\
\frac {\partial f}{\partial y} = 2(y-9) +\lambda = 0\\
\frac {\partial f}{\partial y} = y-x^2 = 0$

From the first equation, either $x = 0$ or $\lambda = 1$

If $x = 0$ then $(0,0)$ is a critical point.  It looks like this is a local maximum.

If $\lambda = 1$
$2y - 17 =0\\
y = \frac {17}{2}$

This appears to be your error.

$(\sqrt \frac {17}{2} , \frac {17}{2})$ is a critical point.

Plugging this into:

$D^2 = x^2 + (y-9)^2\\
D^2 = \frac {17}{2} + (\frac {17}{2}-9)^2\\
D^2 = \frac {35}{4}$

$D$ is slightly less than $3$